# Android: ActionBarSherlock search widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I currently have an application in the play store for both tablets and smartphone runnings Android 3.0+ (http://tinyurl.com/cnejnjs). In order to appeal to more users I am looking into getting the application to work on a large range of devices.

I am aware of ActionBar Sherlock and this seems to do almost everything I want. One thing it does not offer is the [Search Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget) which I make use of in the current application.

Is there any way to have a search box in the actionbar which updates the current list fragment on screen in a similar way to how the default search widget works?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The search widget is just a simple expandable action item. You can create your own very easily by using an `EditText` as the expanded layout. You can see this in the "Collapsible Action Item" example from the [Feature Demos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos) (though it is only a very basic example).

You can also use the built-in widget on Honeycomb and up from the compatibility library:

```
Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
View searchView = SearchViewCompat.newSearchView(context);
if (searchView != null) {
    //Use native implementation
} else {
    //Use simple compatibility implementation
}
```

Supporting a 99% compatibile implementation is also [on the roadmap](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/70).

Comment: I tried Collapsible Action Item demo, but I dont know how to get reference to the EditText.

Comment: You either inflate the layout in code and call `findViewById` or you specify the layout in the menu XML and then call `getActionView().findViewById(...)`

Comment: How can I attach listeners? I can't typecast from View to SearchViewCompat

Comment: @jake : how do i "specify the layout in the menu XML" ?